# PHP/MYSQL Query to be grouped by another array

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, group-by

My today's need, and I hope you will find the great solution, is the following.
I have a DB table with tasks, each of them with a status "open" or "closed". In my case I have only records with open tasks.

I need to build an array showing all status options (open, closed) and inside of each of them the tasks which are open or closed, if they exists.
Output should be:

```
Array (
  [open] => Attay(task1), Array(task2),..
  [closed] => Array()  
)
```

If I make the sql query:

```
select task_id,status from tasks group by status
```

I get only the tasks inside "open". Which is the best way to build the status Array and "append" inside of each of them the tasks with that status?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `GROUP_CONCAT` to collect all the tasks for each status into a comma separated list and then `explode` that into an array in PHP. Assuming you are using `mysqli` and your connection is in `$conn`, you would do something like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT status, GROUP_CONCAT(task_id) AS taskids FROM tasks GROUP BY status";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$output = array();
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $output[$row['status']] = explode(',', $row['taskids']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In pure SQL, you can generate a derived table of statuses with `union all`, then bring your original table with a `left join`:

```
select
    s.status,
    json_arrayagg(t.task_id) json_task_ids
from (
    select 'open' status
    union all select 'closed' status
) s
left join tasks t on t.status = s.status
group by s.status
```

MySQL does not have an `array` datatype, so this brings the list of task ids as a json array. Another option is to build a comma separated lists: for this, you can use `group_concat()`:

```
select
    s.status,
    group_concat(t.task_id) csv_task_ids
from (
    select 'open' status
    union all select 'closed' status
) s
left join tasks t on t.status = s.status
group by s.status
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
$sql = "SELECT task_id, status FROM tasks";

$status['open'], status['close'] = [];

while( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ) {

    if ($row['status'] == 'open') {
        array_push($status['open'], $row['task_id']);
    }

    if ($row['status'] == 'close') {
        array_push($status['close'], $row['task_id']);
    }
}

print_r($status);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everybody for contributions.

I solved in this way.

```
  $statusArray = ['opened', 'wait_others', 'wait_us', 'closed'];
  foreach ($statusArray as $status) {
    $ticketsArray[$status]= array();
  }
  foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
    $ticketsArray[$value->status_title][$value->ticket_id]= $row[$key];
  }
  print"<pre>";print_r($ticketsArray);
```